# Hypernym for "individual" and "company"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Could anyone let me know any good umbrella term for *individual* and *company*?

I'm trying to create a form as below. And I need a word or phrase to fill the blank:

> _____: individual/company
>   name: [name]
>   sex: male/female
>   marital status: married/single

Comment: A *legal-person* is any such word. If it's not what you're looking for, please provide some context.

Comment: We need more context to be able to help. Will there only be two options? What if it is an NGO? Or a fan club? Or a church? What is this for? How can a company be married?

Comment: Are all these going to have just two choices? Just asking, but I assume you know there are several more marital statuses than you have listed.

Comment: sex and marital status are just examples for choosing input. Company can be utility company like "Foobar Gas". Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an automated data input facility, which would be better asked on [SO User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "indivisual or company" is has only choice. Any another questions are just examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I will try it if I cannot find an answer

Comment: @shirakia: As others have said, I think you still need to provide more context (whichever site you end up on). For example, what if any *difference* does it make if the "user" fills in his company name rather than his *personal* name? Maybe you're offering "corporate membership" as well as "individual membership". In which case it's not uncommon to see something like ***(of company, if applying for a corporate account)*** after the ***name*** legend. I'm no expert on this kind of stuff, but I don't really think it's exactly a matter of "normal use of English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot. Yes I want to ask "corporate membership" or "individual membership". It might be "type of membership" or just "membership"

Comment: Or... Membership type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Entity? For instance, both a person and a corporation count as a legal entity.